# How to prove that $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ is dense in $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, matrices

This question is inspired by an old question on here.

> **Prove:**
>
> $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ is dense in $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $

Proof:

$ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) : \det A \neq 0\}$ where $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ consists of all $n \times n$ matrices with real entries.

We want to prove that $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ is dense in $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $.

$ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ is dense in $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ if every matrix $A \in {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ either belongs to $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ or is a limit point of $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $.

A matrix $P$ is a limit point of $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ in $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ if and only if every open set $U$ containing $P$ also contains  a point of $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ different from
$P$.

---

And now when we should start to think I am not sure what to do as I have never worked with $ {\mathbf{GL}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ or $ {\mathbf{M}_{n}}(\mathbb{R}) $ before.

I would appreciate a hint or a few on how to continue.

Comment: If you think of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, can you find matrices close to $A$ whose determinant is nonzero?

Comment: Under what topology? Spectral norms?

Comment: @Vim Yes, that is of course important. It is
the usual topology
of euclidean $n^2$-space, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let $A\in M_n$. Choose $\epsilon >0$ such that $\epsilon$ is less than the smallest positive eigenvalue of $A$ (if any exists, otherwise any positive $\epsilon$ will do). Observe that $A-\epsilon I$ is invertible (otherwise, $\epsilon$ is an eigenvalue for $A$), therefore $A_\epsilon \in GL_n$.

Comment: I am a little out of my depth here when it comes to linear algebra because i have not studied linear algebra in a long time. But these things you mention I might be able to work with. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I have a basic question. If $A$ is not invertible so there is no such $\epsilon$?   If I understood you well it not just simply necessary to chose any $\epsilon >0$ that is different of any eigen value

Answer (score 17):

I particularly like this argument. Take any matrix $A$ and any invertible matrix $B$. Consider $$p(t) = \det((1-t)A+tB)$$ which is clearly a polynomial in one variable, and it is not zero polynomial because $p(1)\neq 0$. Thus, it has finitely many zeroes. That means that you can find arbitrarily small $t$ such that $C_t = (1-t)A+tB$ is invertible and we have $$\|A-C_t\| = |t|\|A-B\|<\varepsilon,\quad |t|<\frac{\varepsilon}{\|A-B\|}$$ Geometrically, we consider a line segment through matrices $A$ and $B$ and can find invertible matrix on it arbitrarily close to $A$.

Comment: Yes, this argument i really like too!

Answer (score 14):

The function $\det g$ is a polynomial in the $g_{ij}$. In particular, it's equal to its Taylor series everywhere. It follows that the closed set $X = \{g\in M_n(\mathbb{R}):\, \det g = 0\}$ has empty interior, and thus its complement $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is dense.

Comment: That's nice and quick.

Comment: +1 Why does it follow that X has empty interior?

Comment: @JKnecht: If it contained an open ball, then the Taylor series of $\det g$ around the center of that ball would vanish.

Answer (score 8):

The set $X$ of matrices with zero determinant is a submanifold of codimension $1$ (with some singularities). Then by [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem) it has measure zero. It follows that its complement is dense.

Comment: +1 Sard's theorem was new for me, and reading about it I also learned about null sets, Lebesgue measure etc.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about how Sard's theorem applies here?  I'm a little unclear what mapping you're applying it to, since it doesn't appear that $\det: \mathbf{M}_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ is what you want.  Thanks!

Comment: Assume $N$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ of codimension $>0$. Work in a chart $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$ of $M$ and apply Sard to the inclusion of (a subset of) $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A \in M_n(K)$, with $K=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, then $\chi_A(\lambda)=\det\left(A-\lambda I_n \right)$ is a nonzero polynomial, so it has a finite number of roots. So it exits a $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k>p \text{, }$ $\chi_A(1/k)\neq 0$ and then the sequence $$\left(A-\frac{1}{k} \cdot I_n\right)_{k>p}\longrightarrow A$$

is made of invertible matrices.

QED.

Comment: Great answer thank you!

Answer (score 5):

(1) If $A=[a_1\cdots a_n]$ with ${\rm rank}\ A=k,\ k<n $, then we can
assume that $\{ a_1,\cdots,a_k\}$ is linearly independent. If $
\{a_1,\cdots,a_k, b_{k+1},\cdots, b_n\}$ is linearly independent and if $B:= [ 0\cdots 0\ b_{k+1}\ \cdots\
b_n]$, then ${\rm det}\ (A+ \epsilon B)  = {\rm det} \ [a_1\cdots a_k \ \epsilon b_{k+1}\ \cdots\
\epsilon b_n]\neq 0 $

(2) $M_n({\bf R})$ has a inner product, i.e., $|X|^2={\rm trace}\ XX^T$ and we have a metric $d(X,Y)=|X-Y|$. So since $|A-(A+ \epsilon B)|=\epsilon |B|$ Hence $A$ has an invertible matrix within arbitrary small distance. That is $Gl_n({\bf R})$ is dense.

Comment: +1 The last step there, how does it follow that it is dense?

Comment: I add more explanation